# android camera creates file with 0kb in external sd card folder on camera cancle

Tags: android, camera

a bit issue in my code, please help me to overcome this
i have an activity which captures an image & saves in app folder which is working fin. on click save button it saves the image in folder but when user cancle camera activity then 0kb file is created as well in folder, how to avoid this

here is my code related to camera activity

```
public class camera extends Activity {

    private static final int ACTION_TAKE_PHOTO_B = 1;

    private static final String BITMAP_STORAGE_KEY = "viewbitmap";
    private static final String IMAGEVIEW_VISIBILITY_STORAGE_KEY = "imageviewvisibility";

    private ImageView mImageView;
    private Bitmap mImageBitmap;

    private String mCurrentPhotoPath;

    private static final String JPEG_FILE_PREFIX = "IMG_";
    private static final String JPEG_FILE_SUFFIX = ".jpg";

    private File getAlbumDir() {

        String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
        File filenamedemo = new File(path + "/ImageFolder/");

        String name = String.valueOf(filenamedemo);
        if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(Environment
                .getExternalStorageState())) {

            if (name != null) {
                if (!filenamedemo.mkdirs()) {
                    if (!filenamedemo.exists()) {
                        return null;
                    }
                }
            }

        } else {

        }

        return filenamedemo;
    }

    private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        // Create an image file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss")
                .format(new Date(0));
        String imageFileName = JPEG_FILE_PREFIX + timeStamp + "_";
        File albumF = getAlbumDir();
        File imageF = File.createTempFile(imageFileName, JPEG_FILE_SUFFIX,
                albumF);
        return imageF;
    }

    private File setUpPhotoFile() throws IOException {

        File f = createImageFile();
        mCurrentPhotoPath = f.getAbsolutePath();

        return f;
    }

    private void galleryAddPic() {
        Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(
                "android.intent.action.MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE");
        File f = new File(mCurrentPhotoPath);
        Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
        mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
        this.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
    }

    private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {

        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

        File f = null;

        try {
            f = setUpPhotoFile();
            mCurrentPhotoPath = f.getAbsolutePath();
            takePictureIntent
                    .putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            f = null;
            mCurrentPhotoPath = null;
        }
        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, ACTION_TAKE_PHOTO_B);

    }

    private boolean isDeviceSupportCamera() {
        if (getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(
                PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {
            // this device has a camera
            return true;
        } else {
            // no camera on this device

            return false;
        }
    }

    private void handleBigCameraPhoto() {

        if (mCurrentPhotoPath != null) {
            // setPic();
            // galleryAddPic();
            mCurrentPhotoPath = null;

            Intent viewint = new Intent(camera.this, TashPatti.class);
            startActivity(viewint);
            finish();

        }

    }

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        dispatchTakePictureIntent();

        /*
         * if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.FROYO) {
         * mAlbumStorageDirFactory = new FroyoAlbumDirFactory(); } else {
         * mAlbumStorageDirFactory = new BaseAlbumDirFactory(); }
         */
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == ACTION_TAKE_PHOTO_B) {

            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                Toast.makeText(this, "picture saved.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
                handleBigCameraPhoto();

            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {

                // User cancelled the video capture
                Toast.makeText(this, "User cancelled the image capturing.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } else {

                // Video capture failed, advise user
                Toast.makeText(this, "image capture failed.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
            }
        }
    }

    // Some lifecycle callbacks so that the image can survive orientation change
    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        outState.putParcelable(BITMAP_STORAGE_KEY, mImageBitmap);

        outState.putBoolean(IMAGEVIEW_VISIBILITY_STORAGE_KEY,
                (mImageBitmap != null));

        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        mImageBitmap = savedInstanceState.getParcelable(BITMAP_STORAGE_KEY);
        mImageView.setImageBitmap(mImageBitmap);
        mImageView
                .setVisibility(savedInstanceState
                        .getBoolean(IMAGEVIEW_VISIBILITY_STORAGE_KEY) ? ImageView.VISIBLE
                        : ImageView.INVISIBLE);

    }

}
```

any help will appreciatd,
thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

i solved my issue by deleting the 0 size file, in onActivitiResult(),
i got what i want but it is not clear to me why my code creates 0 size file after cancle operation ??

refrence for others ,enjoy coding

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
     if (requestCode == ACTION_TAKE_PHOTO_B) {

            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                Toast.makeText(this, "picture saved.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data"); 

                byte[] byteData = null;
                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
                byteData = baos.toByteArray();

                //handleBigCameraPhoto();

            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {



                // User cancelled the video capture
                Toast.makeText(this, "User cancelled the image capturing.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } else {


                // Video capture failed, advise user
                Toast.makeText(this, "image capture failed.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            //this code delete the file if itz size is 0, 0 size occers wheen user cancles the 
            //camera activity so to avoid 0 size file in our folder we are deleting it
            File file= filePath;
            Log.i("lengthhh", Long.toString(file.length()));
            if(file.exists() && file.length()==0)
            {
                 file.delete();
            }
            Intent viewint=new Intent(camera.this, TashPatti.class);
            startActivity(viewint); finish();

     }
}
```